# how to fire event on class change by manual?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I do trigle  `.delivery` to fire `change` function ?

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {

     $('.delivery').change(function(e) {
         var total = 0 ;
         var price = 0 ;
         ....
```

Comment: something missing in code? Do `$('.delivery').change();` that will trigger change event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question been asked seems to be half because you didn't add the added class name here. If you are just adding the class name to the target element then you just have to do this:

```
$('.delivery').change();  // <---will trigger the change.
```

If you are removing the old class then you have to rethink the code. Then you have to make a function and call it like a callback:

```
function firechange(){
    console. log(event.type);
    // put the code for change event
}

$('.delivery').change(firechange);
```

Now when you remove and add a new class then after adding the class you have to bind the change event because this class doesn't hold any event. This class has been added to the DOM node after page load.

Suppose you added a class `newclass` and removed the old one from the element:

```
    $('.delivery').removeclass('delivery')
                          .addclass('newclass');

    $('.newclass').change(firechange).change(); // <--bind here and trigger.
```

Or this way:

```
    $('.delivery').removeclass('delivery')
                          .addclass('newclass')
                          .change(firechange);

    $('.newclass').change(); // <--bind here and trigger.
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
$('.delivery').trigger('change');
```

Comment: You might want to `$('.delivery').triggerHandler('click')` unless you actually need to fire the event.

Comment: that's the thing - OP already has the event hooked up. So I'm guessing they're asking how to fire it.

Answer (score 0):

How about a custom Event eg.

```
$('#myelement').trigger($.Event('divchange.namespace'));
```

and you can listen for it , like so:

```
 $(document).on('divchange.namespace' , '#myelement', function(){
  // do something
 });
```

If all you want to know , is how to fire a event manually , use [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).